# How to return from yield *

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator

Is there any way to return from a `yield * asyncIterator`?

**Background:**

Given an async iterator like this:

```js
const asyncIterator = {
  next () {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('next'), 500))
  },
  return () {
    return Promise.resolve('return')
  },
  [Symbol.asyncIterator] () {
    return this
  }
}
```

the following will never invoke its `return` method:

```js
async * yieldFromIterator () {
  yield 'start'
  yield * asyncIterator
}

const yieldingIterator = yieldFromIterator()
console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // 'start'
console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // 'next'
console.log(await yieldingIterator.return()) // never resolved
```

neither does this:

```js
async * yieldFromIterator () {
  yield 'start'
  for await (const result of asyncIterator) {
    yield result
  }
}

const yieldingIterator = yieldFromIterator()
console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // 'start'
console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // 'next'
console.log(await yieldingIterator.return()) // never resolved
```

while the following of course does:

```js
async * returnIterator () {
  yield 'start'
  return asyncIterator
}

const returningIterator = returnIterator()
console.log(await returningIterator.next()) // 'start'
console.log(await returningIterator.next()) // 'next'
console.log(await returningIterator.return()) // 'return'
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Try `return yield* …`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `asyncIterator` has an error: The fulfillment value of the promise [must be a *result object*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-asynciterator-interface) (an object implementing the [IteratorResult interface](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iteratorresult-interface), which has the shape `{done, value}`). But you're fulfilling the promise with a string instead.

If you update it to return a result object instead, you'll see the return:

```js
const asyncIterator = {
  next () {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({value: 'next', done: false}), 500))
  },
  return () {
    return Promise.resolve({value: 'return', done: true})
  },
  [Symbol.asyncIterator] () {
    return this
  }
}

async function * yieldFromIterator () {
  yield 'start'
  yield * asyncIterator
}

(async function() {
  const yieldingIterator = yieldFromIterator()
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.next())   // {value: 'start', done: false}
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.next())   // {value: 'next', done: false}
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.return()) // {value: 'return', done: true}
})().catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Separately, `asyncIterator` has another issue (not necessarily a bug): It doesn't inherit from [%AsyncIteratorPrototype%](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-asynciteratorprototype) and the chain below it. In theory, code could add methods to %AsyncIteratorPrototype%, %IteratorPrototype%, etc., and those would be missing from `asyncIterator`.

In general, async generator functions are the best way to create async iterator objects (because async generators are async iterators), just like non-async generator functions are the best way to create iterators. You get the benefit of `yield` syntax and inheriting from the standard prototypes.

That said, if you implemented `asyncIterator` with an async generator function, you wouldn't see your `'return'` string in response to that `return` call. You'd need to call `next`, and use `return` in `yieldFromIterator`:

```js
const delay = (ms, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args));

const asyncIterator = (async function*() {
  await delay(500);
  yield 'next';
  return 'return';
})();

async function * yieldFromIterator () {
  yield 'start'
  return yield * asyncIterator // <=== Added `return`
}

(async function() {
  const yieldingIterator = yieldFromIterator()
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // {value: 'start', done: false}
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // {value: 'next', done: false}
  console.log(await yieldingIterator.next()) // {value: 'return', done: true}
  // Changed to `next` −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
})().catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into a fair bit of detail on this in Chapters 6 and 9 of my new book (see my profile for links/details).

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer - will definitely give your book a try :)